# I tried to call a function and PHP thinks that I'm trying to redeclare it

Tags: php, function, call, redefine, redeclare

I have a function called "logToFile" and I'm trying to call it but PHP is thinking that I'm trying to redeclare it.

logToFile:

```
function logToFile($msg) {
$filename = "log.txt";
$fd = fopen($filename, "a");
$str = "[" . date("Y/m/d h:i:s", mktime()) . "] " . $msg;
fwrite($fd, $str . "\n");
fclose($fd);
```

My call to the function:

```
logToFile("$user->username kicked $arg1 for $arg2.");
```

Help please?

Comment: Do you have a closing bracket as well?
Is the function not secretly inside a class? Is it declared in the same file or is that file included?

Comment: Maybe you included the file where your function is in more than once?

Comment: if PHP says that you're redeclaring it, then you do! Try changing the function name and see if it works.

Comment: Does the error message have a line number? Is it really the line where you call the function?

Comment: @Barmar: `Is it really the line where you call the function?` The line number in error message will be the line where the function was first *redefined*, no? ([demo](http://3v4l.org/CWjeC))

Comment: @AmalMurali The error message contains both. The original line is in `previously declared in /pathname:3`, the redefinition is in `on line 4`.

Comment: @Barmar: Sorry, that's what I meant. Please see the updated comment.

Comment: @AmalMurali That was my point. The question says that when he tries to call the function, it's reporting it as a redefinition. I was suggesting that he check the line number in the error message to see which line is really causing the error, because it's probably _not_ the line where he tries to call the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, PHP is not dumb. If PHP says you're re-declaring a function, well, then you are. When the function definition occurs multiple times, PHP will throw a Fatal error, similar to the one below:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare logToFile() (previously declared in /path/to/script:**X**) in /path/to/script on line **Y**

Here, X is the line where you originally declared the function, and Y is where you tried to **re-declare** (not *call*, as you state in the question) the function. Check your code to find this line, and remove it.

And to avoid errors like this, you can first check whether a function was defined using [`function_exists()`](http://php.net/function_exists) and then try to declare it:

```
if (!function_exists('logToFile')) {
    function logToFile($msg) {
        $filename = "log.txt";
        $fd = fopen($filename, "a");
        $str = "[" . date("Y/m/d h:i:s", mktime()) . "] " . $msg;
        fwrite($fd, $str . "\n");
        fclose($fd);
    }
} else {
    echo 'Trying to re-declare the function';
}
```

While the above method will help you avoid fatal errors, I **strongly** suggest you figure out where you're redefining the function and correct that instead. Most of the times, this will be due to multiple includes of the file containing your function. In that case, you can simply use [`require_once()`](http://php.net/require_once) instead. PHP will check if the file has already been included, and if so, not include (require) it again.

Comment: Just exactly what I was going to write!! :D

Comment: While this will stop the error, it seems like the wrong way to go about it. Figure out why you're trying to redefine the function in the first place, and fix it.

Comment: Really not a fan of your `function_exists` approach. It has no benefits over just having PHP display an error and bloats code enormously.

Comment: @Duncan: I agree -- which is why I've included the additional note at the end of my answer.